# How to align exactly more bones in pose mode

Tags: modeling, rigging, bones, snapping

I would like to align 10 bones,called DEF_arm bones,to existing bones,called MCH_armSpline bones but I don't know how to do it. I tried selecting all the bones together and a bone at a time and then I did `snap/selection to cursor`,but it didn't work. Also I don't understand why, in edit mode, ALL the bones are perfectly aligned together, but not in pose mode. I attached a short video to show you,thanks.

[what happens](https://sendvid.com/szz5ywqv)

NB : I know how to put bones into the position the were originally in, aka the "rest position" ; I do <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> ; <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> ; <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>" and it worked,but,as you can see from this picture, the last bones that I aligned aren't on the same position with the others.:

[image]
[pic1](http://postimg.org/image/hi8rjcgsb)

And if you look at this pic you will see that on the tutorial that I'm following all the bones are perfectly aligned also in pose mode:

[image]
[pic2](http://postimg.org/image/z9kdxsw6z)

.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the bones have some constraints on them.  Have you tried deleting those constraints and trying to reset their transforms?

Comment: the constraints are in each bone. I don't understand which of them I have to delete. If I attach the blend file,can you give a look ?

Comment: Sure I don't mind.  But please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to attach it, and add the link to the original question.  This allows the .blend to be permanently stored,and more people can look at it.

Comment: added it. refresh the page...

Comment: hello,somebody is there ? I think I found where is error,but I don’t know how to fix it. Please,compare these two videos : 1) https://sendvid.com/qxi8yayl and 2) https://sendvid.com/gnsannlu. The first is a little piece of the tutorial and the second shows what happened to me. You can see that on the tutorial the bone chain moves from the top to the bottom and viceversa,but mine moves from the left to the right and viceversa. So,something is not working good on my side...

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for not responding until now -- I got busy and this totally slipped my mind!  Has the issue since been solved?